# Sorting Genome Strings in C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm creating a program that is meant to sort genome strings, and I've run into an issue with the output.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string genome;
    cout << "Enter a genome string: ";
    cin >> genome;

        int geneCounter = 0;

while(!genome.empty())  //enters loop if strings not empty
{

if(genome.find("ATG") == string::npos)
{   
    if(geneCounter == 0)
    {
    cout << "No gene is found";  
    genome.clear(); 
    }
return 0;
}
else
{
    int startGene = genome.find("ATG");
    int endGene = min(min(genome.find("TAG"), genome.find("TAA")), genome.find("TGA"));

    string currentGene = genome.substr(startGene + 3, endGene - (startGene +3));

    if((currentGene.length() % 3) == 0)
    {
        geneCounter += 3;
        cout << currentGene <<endl;
    }

    endGene += 3;
    genome.erase(0, endGene);
    cout << genome;
}
}

return 0;
}
```

The code itself runs fine, it displays "No gene is found" correctly and doesn't stick me in a loop of not closing.

However, the string I'm being asked to test it with (TTATGTTTTAAGGATGGGGCGTTAGTT), does not output the correct results.

Whenever I input the string I get the following:

```
TTT
GGATGGGGCGTTAGTTGGGCGT
TT
```

When I should be getting:

```
TTT
GGGGCGT
```

I feel like I'm missing something very simple, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're `cout`ing the entire `genome` string at the end of each loop. I don't think you want to be. Remove that line, and you get the output you expect.

Comment: Also, I could be wrong about this, but it looks like you're saying if `currentGene.length() % 3` is not 0, it means the text between `startGene` and `endGene` is not actually a gene (which makes biological sense). But in that case, instead of deleting all that text anyway, I think you want to look for the next ATG beginning at `startGene + 3`.

Comment: And the sequence "ATGA" could cause you trouble too, since it contains an overlapping "ATG" and "TGA". Search for `endGene` starting from `startGene + 3` to prevent this (this would also prevent you from finding an `endGene` that begins *before* `startGene`).

Comment: Deleting the cout line fixed the whole issue :) Thank you so much! I'll try implementing the other suggestions you provided as well.

Comment: I don't know your exact requirements, so take them with a grain of salt. I used to TA bioinformatics classes and old habits die hard. :)